# Issue with assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, uthash

Hey so im trying to attempt to read in a file, store it in a hash and then copy it. However i get the incompatible pointer type

```
struct hash_struct {
    int id;                   
    char name[BUFFER_SIZE];            /* key (string WITHIN the structure */
    UT_hash_handle hh;         /* makes this structure hashable */
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char *lines[80];
    FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
    if(fgets(*lines, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
    {
        puts(*lines);
        // do something
    }
    fclose(fp);
    const char **n;
    char *names[1024];
    strcpy(*names, *lines);
    struct hash_struct *s, *tmp, *users = NULL;
    int i=0;
for (n = names; *n != NULL; n++) 
{
    s = (struct hash_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct hash_struct));
    strncpy(s->name, *n,10);
    s->id = i++;
    HASH_ADD_STR( users, name, s );
}

HASH_FIND_STR( users, "joe", s);
if (s) printf("joe's id is %d\n", s->id);
printf("Hash has %d entries\n",HASH_COUNT(users));

/* free the hash table contents */
HASH_ITER(hh, users, s, tmp) {
  HASH_DEL(users, s);
  free(s);
}
return 0;
```

}

The code works when i initialize `const char **n, *names = {array elements here};`
But it doesnt work with the code i have. Please help.

Comment: `char *lines[80];`..`if(fgets(*lines, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL)` change to `char lines[80];`..`if(fgets(lines, sizeof lines, fp) != NULL)` and  `char *names[1024];strcpy(*names, *lines);` --> `char names[1024];strcpy(names, lines);//remove '\n'`

Comment: don't write `*` if you don't konw what it means

Answer (score 0):

`lines` is declared to be an array of `char` pointers, but doesn't allocate any space for the strings they point to.  In your working version, the compiler took care of allocating space for each string.

Plus, you can't use `strcpy` to copy an array of 80 pointers to an array of 1024 pointers.
Instead, each line you read in needs space to be allocated for it to be read into; then the addresses of each of those can be assigned to an element of `names`.  In fact, as @BLUEPIXY suggests, `line` should be an array of 80 `char`s, not an array of 80 pointers-to-`char`s.  Or you could just `malloc` the space for each new line, and put the address of that line into `names`.

Comment: I tried allocating memory using malloc but i get the same issue. The issue seems to be when the program trys to call on n or names

Comment: I tried using just BUFFER_SIZE for both the arrays but i still cant seem to get it to work. Im not understanding which pointer is not working and why.